# Decrypting RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider in .NET8

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

I have connectionstring of my application defined in a seperate config file. While migrating to .NET8 im facing platform not supported error when trying to decrypt it. Is there any way to decrypt it in c#?

Here is my config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
                </KeyInfo>
                <CipherData>
                    <CipherValue>lT+4rnY5uXs2FXfNh4PSZOzbihEyLNOHH2+aQB2mAuElk6NBLFtEKKGr+V0nUDE74w4N1zX00nWUqM2A3u5RiPc3NSxY3qF/Ff5CxMdmTIpmPpyJ1aIfPF4ldCAePQksikahbsMXk5+MREBZ+kzsEsCvoQa/JrjO/1oz/tG9vZZCG3GD/Rsp1PbVX1IKdy2WrEO1cp4YQVLdPmXJM7TkvXabz3mIptLfb2qI/csZ8ZvHHPFDXtd4aM6BBibO5MINAR0eeFPZU1gtkXxv+h+i5szht0O/FlP4nrLfBM/6Wz7Y4QEZJRBKaIicbzizqqjzIG6B4n2Ho6+3ImAf3XLTDw==</CipherValue>
                </CipherData>
            </EncryptedKey>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```